# What causes a JSON response to be surrounded by quotes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, endpoint

I've setup an API endpoint in `App1` and am posting to it to create a user record from `App2`.

I've set `App1` to respond with JSON but the JSON response is surrounded quotes (and filled with backslashes). I understand backslashes are used to escape quotes but it still seems weird.

**Expected response**

```
{id:8, first_name:"Long", last_name:"John Silver", email:"1@example.com", temp_password:"ydKrDdd9zbrGzrm-uMK8"}
```

**Actual response**

```
"{\"id\":8,\"first_name\":\"Long\",\"last_name\":\"John Silver\",\"email\":\"1@example.com\",\"temp_password\":\"ydKrDdd9zbrGzrm-uMK8\"}"
```

**Routes**

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users, :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.temp_password = Devise.friendly_token
    if @user.save
        render json: @user
    else
        render json: {res: "Something went wrong"}
    end
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :temp_password)
end
```

Is it possible to get a response like "expected response" above?
What might be causing this?

Thanks kindy.

Comment: I know nothing about Ruby on Rails, but it looks to me like something's rendering it *twice*: The first time it gets correctly transformed from a User object into JSON (e.g., a string), but then apparently it gets rendered as JSON *again*. If you pass just a string value to a JSON renderer, it will put quotes around it and escape quotes within it. So that's where I'd look, for an extra layer of rendering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
 JSON.parse(response)
```

to get what you expected.
Depending on your setup and where the request is coming from, you might have to use:

```
JSON.parse(response).with_indifferent_access
```

To be able to use quotes or symbols.

Comment: Is it common to deal with JSON responses like this in Rails, or do you think my app has something "funky" causing it?

Comment: Nope this is common don't worry